# Does Irelia's Q apply W effects?

Tags: league-of-legends

W's passive is to get a small amount of health points per autoattack. If I activate it, gets twice and also applies some true damage.

Since Irelia's Q (Bladesurge) applies on-hit effects, will also apply W effects, passive or active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Irelias Q applies all On-Hit effects including her W. You will deal bonus true damage with q and you will also be healed for the right amount (passive and active). It even applies things such as Wits ends passive, Spellblade Procs (Sheen,Iceborn,Triforce,Lichbane) and even Lifesteal.

Note however that Jax E, Pantheon passive, Fiora W and Teemo blind will completely Negate the damage **and** On-hit effects. A spell shield will also Negate the damage. The spell is very similar to Ezreals Q.

Comment: I really want to know how they decide how the different reactions between champions...  Poppy (and I believe Nasus but not sure) can both ignore Jax's dodge and Pantheons shield with their on hit attacks and still proc the additional effects.